# Java JOptionPane: How to take an user input in String and store it in an array?

Tags: java, joptionpane

```java
String jobName;
jobName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Job Name " + i);
String[] numberofjobs; 
numberofjobs = new String[jobName];
```

I'm trying to take an user input as a String and store into an array, what am I doing wrong here?

I'm also trying to take multiple inputs of different data types (e.g. int and String) and have them correspond to each other. How do I go about this?

Comment: You haven’t shown us the enclosing loop, but a good start is realizing that you want to create a single array to hold all job names.  You do not want to create a new array for each job name entered.

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```java
String[] numberofjobs = new String[10];
String jobName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Job Name " + i);

if(jobName != null) {
    numberofjobs[0] = jobName;
}
```

Learn more about arrays [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

What you can do if you want ints (since JOptionPane.showInputDialog will return a String), is use `Integer.parseInt(jobName);` where **jobName** is the user input.

This code will store all values from **String[]** into **int[]**, you can place it after the first code sample:

```java
int[] intArray = new int[numberofjobs.length];

for (int i = 0; i < numberofjobs.length; i++) {
    intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberofjobs[i]);
}
```

To **'link'** the **salary** to **jobName** you just have to be sure that the values are in the same index, than to get the job name and salary you can just do this:

```java
String jobNameAndSalary = numberofjobs[0] + ", with the salary of " + salaries[0];
```

Best regards,
Brhaka

Comment: Hey thanks. I'm trying to assign a String (jobName) to an int user input so they correspond each other. For example, String[1] will be Number[1]. How do I do this?

Comment: You want to make the **String[1]** value to be applied into the **int[1]** value?

Comment: Yeah, I want them to be "linked".

Comment: I made an edit, take a look and tell me if it is what you're looking for. plz

Comment: Is there a way I can message you? I want to show you my code but it's too long.

Comment: Ok. What's the problem? Why my last code sample don't  works? Maybe if you tell me more details I can help you.

Comment: Ok, I saw it, but what's the problem? What you can't do?

Comment: I don't know how and where to assign the salary to the job name (both being user inputs).

Comment: Ok, I'll add the solution into my answer.